How to a schema for file upload form in nextjs with zod
nextjs: 14.2.5
zod: 3.23.8
wanted to create a schema for a file upload form.
option 1:
export const fileUploadSchema = z.object({
    file: z.instanceof(File)
})

option 2:
export const fileUploadSchema = z.object({
    file: z.any()
           .refine((file: File) => {file?.size !== 0, "File is required"})
           .refine((file: File) => checkFileType(file), "Only .xlsx file is supported")
})

Both options do not work. No matter what type of file I select in the file input field. With option 1, I get Input not instance of File error; with option 2, I get Invalid input error.
Also there is the A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled warning in browser console in both cases.
Here is my form component embedded in a dialog:
                <Form {...form}>
                <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                    <FormField 
                        control={form.control}
                        name="file"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                                <FormLabel className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">File</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl>
                                    <Input className="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400"
                                        type="file"
                                        {...field} />
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormMessage />
                            </FormItem>
                        )}
                    />
                    <DialogFooter className="gap-2 pt-2 sm:space-x-0">
                        <DialogClose asChild>
                            <Button type="button" variant="outline">
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                        </DialogClose>
                        <Button disabled={isUpdatePending}>
                            {isUpdatePending && (
                                <ReloadIcon
                                    className="mr-2 size-4 animate-spin"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                />
                            )}
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </DialogFooter>
                </form>
            </Form>


To handle file uploads in React/NextJS with Zod, you need to implement the input handling and the validation of the fields differently since file inputs work differently than other inputs in HTML forms

Use this Zod Schema for the validation of the file:



import { z } from 'zod';

const checkFileType = (file) => {
  return file.type === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'; // MIME type for .xlsx
};

export const fileUploadSchema = z.object({
  file: z
    .any()
    .refine((file) => file instanceof File && file.size > 0, {
      message: 'File is required',
    })
    .refine(checkFileType, {
      message: 'Only .xlsx file is supported',
    }),
});




Handle the file inputs

These should be treated as uncontrolled components, don't bind them directly to the form state instead  use a seperate state to handle it for example:
import { useState } from 'react';

const YourFormComponent = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (!file) {
      console.error("No file selected");
      return;
    }
    
    // Create form data
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    // Handle form submission
    console.log('Submitting form data', formData);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div className="form-item">
        <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
          File
        </label>
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={handleFileChange}
          className="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

or you could use react-dropzone library to streamline the file management and validation
Modify the Schema for the validation:
Nothing much to change here, now the validation will be done on the react-dropzone end
import { z } from 'zod';

const checkFileType = (file) => {
  return file.type === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'; // MIME type for .xlsx
};

export const fileUploadSchema = z.object({
  file: z
    .instanceof(File)
    .refine((file) => file.size > 0, {
      message: 'File is required',
    })
    .refine(checkFileType, {
      message: 'Only .xlsx file is supported',
    }),
});

React Component modified code with React Dropzone:
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

const YourFormComponent = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);

  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
      setFile(acceptedFiles[0]); // Set the first file
    }
  }, []);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: '.xlsx', // Restrict file type
  });

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!file) {
      console.error("No file selected");
      return;
    }
    
    // Validate with Zod
    const validationResult = fileUploadSchema.safeParse({ file });

    if (!validationResult.success) {
      console.error(validationResult.error.errors);
      return;
    }

    // Handle form submission
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    console.log('Submitting form data', formData);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <div {...getRootProps()} className="dropzone">
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? (
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p>
        ) : (
          <p>Drag 'n' drop a .xlsx file here, or click to select one</p>
        )}
      </div>
      {file && <p>Selected file: {file.name}</p>}
      <button type="submit" disabled={!file}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

